# Class variable not declared in this scope error c++

Tags: c++

I'm having problem with the function `DisplayValues()` in this program. First, I'm asked to write the prototype only for the function inside the class. Second requirement is to place the entire function `DisplayValues()` outside the class. `DisplayValues()` is a const inline member function.

All the above needs to be in a header file. I've written below and got errors `"'accountType' not declared in this scope"` for the `DisplayValues()` function. I did search for solutions but none worked without modifying the requirements above. Would anyone please advise?

My codes:

File SavingsAccount.h

```
ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H

class SavingsAccount
{
    private:
        int accountType;

    public:
        inline void DisplayValues() const;
};

inline void DisplayValues() 
{
    cout << "Account type: " << accountType << '\n'
}
#endif //SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
```

---

File SavingsAccount.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;

void SavingsAccount::GetInitialValues()
{
    cout << "Enter account type:\n";
    cin >> accountType;   
}
```

---

File main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SavingsAccount ac;
    ac.GetInitialValues();
    ac.DisplayValues();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have declared, but never defined, the member function `SavingsAccount::DisplayValues`. You have defined a standalone, non-member function `::DisplayValues`; in that function, `accountType` is not a known identifer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 3 obvious problems that I can see:

1. This is a free function, not a *class member function*.

```
inline void DisplayValues() 
{
    cout << "Account type: " << accountType << '\n'
}
```

Fix:

```
inline void SavingsAccount::DisplayValues() 
{
    cout << "Account type: " << accountType << '\n'
}
```

2. Your *declaration* is `inline void DisplayValues() const;` but *definition* is missing the `const` keyword.

```
inline void SavingsAccount::DisplayValues() 
                                            ^^^^^ const missing here
```

3. You are missing a semicolon is this line:

```
    cout << "Account type: " << accountType << '\n'
                                                   ^^ semicolon missing here
```